# How to write a correct path with customer package?

Tags: python

In my case, the folder tree like this:

```
 demo/
    ├── lib/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── config.ini
    │   └── onedrive.py
    └── main.py
```

onedrive.py:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read('./config.ini')

...
```

main.py:

```
from lib import onedrive

print(onedrive.get_file("xxx.csv")
```

why the config not found when `$ ~/demo/: python main.py`?

Is there a any way without use `config.read('./lib/config.ini')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to access `config.ini` from `main.py`, you might want to try using the `os` module

when run in `main.py`

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd())

path_to_ini = os.path.join(cwd, 'lib/config.ini')

#do stuff with path_to_ini
```